# Hide, remove or change color of specific class inside external iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I'm trying to embed a google form on my blogger blog but I want to remove or hide somehow the branding link and text that google shows at the end of the form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScKGwCTQXaDGgAucW_dpk3CzOBofXbUrIskKxu_IGR-gssyXQ/viewform?usp=sf_link
Is it possible somehow to hide that or make the text from that class the same as form color so it cant be visible by user? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not!

I've been having the same problem; this is called a Cross Origin Policy issue or CORS for short.

Due to security issues, JS rejects to read or change the content of a page in another domain; so you can't use JS to do this. CSS also only acts on the content on the page but the content of the iframe is not *on* the page.

## But a cross-over

you can use blank rectangles to not let them be shown but it's not really guaranteed.

```css
:root {
  --hiderColor: red;
}

#hider {
  width: 640px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: var(--hiderColor);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScKGwCTQXaDGgAucW_dpk3CzOBofXbUrIskKxu_IGR-gssyXQ/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="937" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="iframe">Loading…</iframe>
<div id="hider"></div>
```

It's not really escape-proof but it does the trick; also I shall say you shouldn't do this!

By the way, I used the red colour so you know how it works you, can change the colour;

And a note: the widths of the div and iframe must be one and the same

Good luck!

Comment: This trick works but if there is a mistake on the form or a paragraph with multiple lines is completed the height of the form will be bigger not fixed and the send button and the bottom of the form will go under the rectangles and won;t be seen anymore....

Comment: Agreed! As I said due to [Cross-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) you can't do this so you can have another server instead of Google for your forms, which I say Google is the best, or accept Google Forms as they are.

Answer (score 0):

External iframe means you have no control on what's inside.

Answer (score -2):

I had that problem for something I made for a class, I used

```
div.a {
display: none;
}
```

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to use

```
<p style="color:black">(Link Here)</p>
```

To recolor the text. Again, I haven't done much restyling of links, but these should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).